# Is Express useful in FIrebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: android, express, google-cloud-functions

I am making an android application that uses firebase for backend services. I want to use cloud functions service. So how common is it to use Express in cloud functions? Is it really necessary or is there any better alternative library provided by firebase that already provides all the functionalities that express does?

Comment: It is very common to use Express.js in Cloud Functions when writing HTTPS-triggered functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using express in cloud functions is pretty standard

there's even a official video for it https://youtu.be/LOeioOKUKI8